# shiny reactive object not found

Tags: r, shiny

I think I'm missing something with respect to reactives in my Shiny app. Here's a MRE that shows my problem printing `y`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Test"),
   textAreaInput("text", "Text", "", width = "400px"),
   verbatimTextOutput("text"),
   actionButton("do", "Run"),
   textOutput("result")
   )

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$do, {
  y <- reactive({
    x <- ""
    t <- 1
    while (t < 5) {
      x <- paste(input$text, x, sep=",")
      t <- t + 1
    }
  })
  })
  output$result <- renderPrint({y})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: in this basic example, if you type "help" into the input box `text`, I'd like to run and print `x`, which would be `help,help,help,help,`

Comment: i'm creating this reactive `y` that is disconnected from what i really want, which is the iteratively pasted `x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't put a reactive value inside of an `observeEvent` or `observe` call. In fact, it has been advised by Joe Cheng to never nest either `observe` or `reactive` functions within either themselves or the other. They are separate things used for different purposes. Since you want the reactive `y` to be created based on when `input$do` is clicked, you should use `eventReactive`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  y <- eventReactive(input$do, {
    x <- ""
    t <- 1
    while (t < 5) {
      x <- paste(input$text, x, sep=",")
      t <- t + 1
    }
    return(x)
  })

  output$result <- renderText({y()})
}
```

I changed `renderPrint()` to `renderText()` so that it displays your desired output. Also, since `y` is a reactive, you need to add `y()` after it in the `renderText()` call. I also added `return(x)` to the `eventReactive` call, otherwise `t` would be the value returned.

Comment: Ah, ok @tbradley. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I the problem is that your call to `reactive()` does not return anything.  Wrapping an expression inside `reactive` assigns the return value of the expression to a variable each time a reactive value inside the expression is changed.  Reactive values are usually all `input$...` variables, and those that you store in `reactiveValues()` objects.

If I get you right you want to change and print `y` every time the "run" button is hit.  Save this to a `reactiveValue()` collection (similarly accessible like a list), and then put this inside your `renderPrint` function.

From your code I reckon that you want `y` to be the value of `x` after the while loop.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  textAreaInput("text", "Text", "", width = "400px"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
  actionButton("do", "Run"),
  textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    x <- ""
    t <- 1
    while (t < 5) {
      x <- paste(input$text, x, sep=",")
      t <- t + 1
    }
    values$y <- x
  })
  output$result <- renderPrint({values$y})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```